# Generate session variable based sequences in MySQL using WHERE but not FROM

Tags: mysql

Thanks for taking an interest

This MySQL problem has been vexing me for some years now, I've decided today is the day to get to the bottom of the issue and find out once and for all if its possible.

Contextually I'd like to generate some lookup tables so my application can access pre calculated information and save time during execution. To do this I need to pre-generate some lists of numbers, one example would be from 0 to 23 representing the hours of the day.

I'm well aware this could be done by just typing these out using UNION ALL between each SELECT on each integer, however I'd like to strive for a more elegant solution and usually use something similar to the following:

```
SET @VCounter := 0;
SELECT (@VCounter := @VCounter + 1) - 1 FROM anyTable WHERE @VCounter < 24;
```

The part thats been vexing me is that I have to use a table (any table containing more than 24 rows) for this to work, even though I'm not using and of the information contained within this table. This annoys me in the following ways:

1) - If the table contains fewer than 24 rows, the statement won't return the full list

2) - I don't need any of the information in the table

What I'd like to be able to use is something closer to the following:

```
SET @VCounter := 0;
SELECT (@VCounter := @VCounter + 1) WHERE @VCounter < 24;
```

However this fails with a syntax error.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to generate this sequence of numbers succinctly and with no wasted code, hopefully I'll learn something new

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: MySql has no any row generator. If you want an elegant way of generating 1000 rows, then use PostgeSQL => `SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,1000)` or Oracle `SELECT level FROM dual CONNECT BY Level <= 1000`. For now in MySql you must use FROM some table or view, maybe in future versions they implement something eqivalent, who knows?

Comment: Thanks Kordirko, I guess I'll just have to wait then...